# How to buy Office 365 User licenses?

Tags: office-365, licensing

Can Anyone help me to figure out, how we can assume user licences in Office 356.
Let us say we have 200 Active Directory users in my local domain,If i want to move to online, do I need to to buy 200 user licenses in Office 365?

Thanks in Advance,

Srinu Dasari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions related to licensing is a bit difficult to answer because Microsoft propose a bunch of plans with packages and options.

You can compare each plan/option from the official [Microsoft comparison table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-plan-options) to find the right model for your business requirements.

To answer your question, “should I buy 200 licenses?”
The answer is yes and no. It depends mainly of the subscription you will choose and for which users you want to give access.

**Note**: you can later on assign different kind of plans to your users according to your subscriptions. Which let you a certain flexibility to feet as much as possible your business needs and optimize your costs.

The best advise I can provide you is contacting Microsoft sales for guiding you.
Or mandating a Microsoft Partner which can accompany you and also negotiate Microsoft contracts on your behalf.